# Заставить Idea 14.1.3 использовать последнюю версию JDK (1.8 вместо 1.5)

Tags: java, ide, intellij-idea

При создании нового проекта в окне указываю конечно же java 1.8. Также в меню file->other settings-> default project structure конечно же указал путь к JDK 1.8.

Однако почему то когда я создаю новый или импортирую сторонний проект, компилятор не воспринимает мои лямбды. Поковырялся - оказалось что версия 1.5 указана аж в двух местах: в настройках модулей проекта: (вызов по F4), настройках проекта (ctrl+shift+alt+s) и в настройках IDE в разделе "build->compiler->java compiler" (который вызывается ctrl+alt+s). В этих двух местах указано 1,5 версия. Я то могу изменить, только проект у меня содержит десяток модулей - кликать придётся на каждом.

КАК заставить эту IDE использовать нормальную, последнюю версию при создании проектов или импорте?

**UPDATE**

Вот что я делаю:

1. закрыл все проекты.
2. нажимаю settings в этом окне:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. нажав settings, вылазит окно "Defaults Settings". В нём указанном пункте выбрано версия 1.8: [image]
4. потом возвращаюсь в первое окно. Снова нажимаю Configure -> Project Defaults -> Settings. Тут тоже самое что и в пункте 2. (указана 1,8 версия). Снова иду на главное окно. Нажимаю Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure и убеждаюсь что путь к java 1.8 указан.  [image]
5. В этом же окне нажимаю вкладку Project, выбираю Java 1.8.45 и уровень языка 8 - Lambdas,Type annotaion. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**В ИТОГЕ,** создав новый проект с нуля, я не могу использовать лямбды. Чтобы это было возможным, мне нужно нажать F4 (или ctrl+alt+shift+s) установить ТАМ версию 1,8 вместо 1,5 для каждого модуля, А ТАКЖЕ нажать alt+shift+s и установить версию 1,8 вместо 1,5 также для каждого модуля. *Надеюсь я понятно объяснил проблему.*

Comment: О, такая же беда. Так не победил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подсказка оказалась в моей любимой IDE - NetBeans. - в Idea я не подключил плагин к maven'y. Посмотрев как создаёт проекты NB, всё стало на свои места.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Идея не отображает, что в плагине указана версия 1.7. Изменил на 1.8 обновилось и компиляция прошла.

Answer (score 1):

1. Сначала надо сделать так, чтобы версия Java по умолчанию была 1.8. Это проще сказать чем сделать :) Проверить просто: с командной строки наберите `java -version` - она и выдаст вам текущую по умолчанию версию Java. Если версия не устраивает надо лезть в настройки оси. Под Windows надо запускать в панель Java в панели управления и выбрать версию по умолчанию. Иногда еще приходится определять переменную среды `JDK_HOME`, `JAVA_HOME`. Если установить правильную дефолтную версию Java, то в дальнейшем при создании новых проектов будет выбираться правильная версия.
2. После того как вы определились с дефолтной Java надо во всех своих модулях указать, что Java compiler наследуется из установок проекта (Project SDK). Тогда установив в настройках проекта Java compiler можно добиться что во всех модулях будет одна и та же Java.

Comment: Версия по-умолчанию у меня 1.8, в проекте вписал 1.8, но не работает. По прежнему не умеет лямбды, типа версия JDK не та. У меня впринципе другой нет. Пробовал Oracle JDK и Open JDK.

Comment: Переформулируйте тогда вопрос - ваш вопрос должен быть: как заставить IDEA понимать лямбды в JDK 1.8

Comment: Error:(13, 59) error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.7
(use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)

Comment: Когда выставляю версию, вот такая ошибка: An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_45). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for java.lang.invoke.MethodType not found

Comment: @Barmaley обновил вопрос. кстати  Алексей Мальченко не автор вопроса.

Answer (score -1):

Preferences -> Build, execution, deployment -> Compiler -> Java compiler -> Project bytecode version

Comment: Я же указал в первом посту. Мне приходится указать ЭТО для каждого нового проекта. Мне нужно избежать указывания для КАЖДОГО проекта.

Comment: Ну, так закройте все проекты в идее - зайдите в конфигурацию и эта настройка станет доступна для проекта по умолчанию. Думал, это очевидно)